Need to change the first column on a set of data every 6th row
I have a set of data where the data stays the same from column 2 to column 6 for every 5 rows and only the first column changes every 6th row:

Is there a formula or any way other than manually doing this?
I did this manually so far but I need to do this for 27 different values for the first column

Use the row() number and if() and then & to join the results

Here's another way, assuming you have Microsoft 365 (in order to use REDUCE etc.)
Enter the following in a cell with enough rows and columns to fill with the generated data:
=LET(
headers,{"Sales Org","Plant","Material Type","Amount","Valid From","Valid To"},
column_data_to_repeat,B3:F7,
sales_org_values,I3:I5,
REDUCE(
headers,
sales_org_values,
LAMBDA(result,sales_org,
VSTACK(result,
HSTACK(TOCOL(DROP(TEXTSPLIT
(REPT(sales_org & ";",ROWS(columns_to_repeat)),";"),0,-1)),column_data_to_repeat))
)))


specifying your ranges for column_data_to_repeat and sales_org_values.
Main loop is:
Build a column by repeating sales_org:

Build a text string by repeating the value with the delimiter (please change this if you data has this delimiter):
REPT(sales_org & ";",ROWS(columns_to_repeat)

Split it into cells:
TEXTSPLIT(REPT(sales_org & ";",ROWS(columns_to_repeat)),";")

Drop the last cell (due to the extra delimiter) and convert it into a column:
HSTACK(TOCOL(DROP( result from step 2 ,0,-1))

Stack this column and block to repeat:
VSTACK(result, result from step 3 ,column_data_to_repeat)


You may want to use a table to hold your sales org values.
Hope this helps for future needs.


Assuming you have a list of values for column 1, you could use:
=INDEX(M$2:M$5,INT((ROW()-2)/5+1))


For columns B to F, you can use =B2 starting at row 7, then populate down and across

